# $p$ is a limit point implies $p\in\overline{E-\{p\}}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E$ be a set, with $p$ as a limit point.

I wish to show that if $p$ is a limit point, $p\in\overline{E-\{p\}}$.

Denote $F=E-\{p\}$.

The converse was proved in class, but for this direction, the proof goes:

Want to show $p\in\overline{F}=F\cup \{\text{all limit points of F}\}=F\cup F^{\prime}$
Since $p\not\in F$ so want to show $p\in F^{\prime}$.

Take each neighbourhood of $p$ to be $B_r(p)$ with radius $r$. Then

$$B_r(p)\cap (F-\{p\} )=\emptyset$$

$$B_r(p)\cap (E-\{p\} )=\emptyset$$

My question is why is the intersection of the ball with $F-\{p\}$ empty? Isn't because $p$ is a limit point (assumption) that any neighborhood intersected with $B_r(p)\cap E-\{p\}\ne\emptyset$ ?

Comment: The proof as written is very unclear.

Comment: I denoted F to be what we want to show. and $F^{\prime}$ is the set of all limit points of $F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show that $F\cap(B_r(p)\smallsetminus\{p\})=B_r(p)\cap(F\smallsetminus\{p\}) ?$

Then it remains you use the (equivalent) definition of closure:

> A point $x$ is in the closure of $A$ if and only if every neighborhood $N$ of $x$ intersects $A$.

Comment: $F\cap (B_r(p) \smallsetminus\{p\})=F\cap (B_r(p)\cap \{p\}^c)=(F\cap \{p\}^c)\cap B_r(p)=B_r(p)\cap (F\smallsetminus \{p\})$

If $p$ is a limit point of $E$, then there is a neighborhood $B_r(p)$ of $p$ such that $B_r(p)\cap E\ne \emptyset$. 

Did this proof use contradiction to assume $p$ is not a limit point so we have $B_r(p)\cap (F\smallsetminus \{p\})=\emptyset$? why is it empty? thank you so much

Comment: @brenna This is a proof using the definition of closure. Think about it! We have proved $p$ is a limit point of $F\iff$ for every nbhd $B_r(p)$ of $p$, $B_r(p)\cap (F\smallsetminus \{p\})$ is nonempty.